# Regex doesn't work on the first time

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string e.g. 02112016. I want to make a datetime from this string.

I have tried:

```
s = "02112016"
s.sub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}")
```

But there is a problem. It returns `"--"`.

If I try this `s.sub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}")` again, it works: `"02-11-2016"`. Now I can use [to_datetime](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime) method.

But why doesn't the `s.sub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}")` work on the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really a simple change here. `$1` and friends are only assigned *after* the match succeeds, not during the match itself. If you want to use immediate values, do this:

```
s = "02112016"
s.sub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3')

# => "02-11-2016"
```

Here `\1` corresponds to what *will be* assigned to `$1`. This is especially important if you're using `gsub` since `$1` tends to be the last match only while `\1` is evaluated for each match individually.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the following.

```
r = /
    \d{2}     # match two digits
    (?=\d{4}) # match four digits in a positive lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

which is the same as

```
r = /\d{2}(?=\d{4})/
```

to be used with [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
s.gsub(r) { |s| "#{s}-" }
```

Try it:

```
"02112016".gsub(r) { |s| "#{s}-" }
  #=> "02-11-2016"
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is the first time you ran it, `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` are empty

You are essentially subbing the numbers for empty strings.

So if we do

```
s = "02112016"

p $1 #=> nil
p $2 #=> nil
p $3 #=> nil

s.sub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}") #=> "--"

p $1 #=> "02"
p $2 #=> "11"
p $3 #=> "2016"

s.sub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "#{$1}-#{$2}-#{$3}") #=> "02-11-2016"
```

That is why it works the second time.

Since the string is always the same length, you can use the `[]` method to break it up.

```
s = "#{s[0..1]}-#{s[2..3]}-#{s[4..-1]}"
```

This will return the desired result

```
"02-11-2016"
```